# Different resolves for multiple entry points

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

Right now I have managed to setup a single webpack configuration and webpack-dev-server (hotload) that managing all my subprojects/plugins at the same time.

However, I would like to be able to resolve folders for each subproject, such as `/components`, so as to avoid long relative paths. Is this possible?

I have the following folder structure

```
-/ MyProject
  -/ node_modules
  -/ plugin1
    -/ node_modules
    - package.json
    ...
  -/ plugin2
  -/ plugin3

-/ shared (styles etc)
- webpack.config.js
- package.json
```

My webpack conf:

var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')

var env = process.env.NODE_ENV;
var isProduction = env === 'production'
var host = 'http://localhost:4000';
var socketHost = 'ws://localhost:4000';

```
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: {
    script: ['webpack-hot-middleware/client', './js/script/src/index.js'],
    app: ['webpack-hot-middleware/client', './js/site/index.js'],
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname , 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  resolve: {
    root: path.resolve(__dirname),
    alias: {
      styles: path.join(__dirname, 'styles'),
      app: path.join(__dirname, 'js', 'site'),
      script: path.join(__dirname, 'js', 'script'),
    }
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(otf|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?.+)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192',
        include: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({ PRODUCTION: false, APP_HOST: JSON.stringify(host), WS_HOST: JSON.stringify(socketHost) }),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(), // recommanded by webpack
    // new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(), // recommanded by webpack
    // new ExtractTextPlugin('bundle.css')
  ]
};
```

Comment: Aren't you already doing that with `resolve.alias`?

Comment: That's a 'global' setting, I want to have a seperate resolve.alias for each of my entry points

Comment: ever find a solution to this?